# Firebase UI Runtime Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm struggling with a strange behavior after updating the version of firebase UI and firebase auth in my project. The error says " Error inflating class TextView", here is the stacktrace:

```
02-24 16:22:15.537 20983-20983/com.nikogalla.tripbook E/AndroidRuntime: 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikogalla.tripbook, PID: 20983
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikogalla.tripbook/com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2891)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1658)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040075 a=4 r=0x7f06002d}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:541)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:913)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:827)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:383)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:97)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1284)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1658)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

This is my app.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    // Firebase
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    // Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    // Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    // Material rating bar
    compile 'com.github.ornolfr:rating-view:0.1.2@aar'
    // User image view library
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    // Google play services location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    // Validation library
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    // Progress bar library
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    // Chip-tag cloud
    compile 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Networking
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

}
    // Add to the bottom of the file
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm not mixing strange versions of firebase UI/ firebase, as documentation of firebase UI says i'm using firebase/play services 11.8.0 with firebase ui 3.2.1. Any clues about this strange issue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean/rebuild?

Comment: Sure, not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was bound to my main activity. I can't understand why but by changing the type of activity from FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity the error disappeared. I've also removed from my gradle support v4 libraries